# Jackson JSON serializer: enable or disable serialisation of certain field in runtime?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have trivial object serialization via Jackson library:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonText = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myComplexObject);
```

I have one field in **myComplexObject** that I sometimes do not want to edn up in serialized result. I know that I can avoid serialization completely if I declare a field in  **myComplexObject** with @JsonIgnore, but I need that field sometimes present in the JSON. Can I achieve this effect? I can assign that field to NULL or to some other special value in case I do not need it.

Comment: you can try the transient keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few ways, from simple JSON Views to `@JsonFilter`, explained at "[Every day Jackson usage, part 3: Filtering properties](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html)" (and its followup, "[Advanced filtering with Jackson, Json Filters](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/09/entry_461.html)")